# teiid doesn't connect to mysql datasource

Tags: mysql, jboss, teiid

I have a problem on connecting to a mysql datasource from JBoss EAP 6.3 with Teiid 8.10.1 copied over it. I need to mention that I've copied mysql connector driver as a module for using mysql datasource. 
  Also, when I try with JBoss EAP 6.3 without Teiid, the connection works.
  Anybody that confronted the same problem?

This is the error message I receive in administration console of JBoss:

> "Unknown error
>
> Unexpected HTTP response: 500
>
> Request {
>       "address" => [
>           ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>           ("data-source" => "database")
>       ],
>       "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool" }
>
> Response
>
> Internal Server Error {
>       "outcome" => "failed",
>       "failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010447: Connection is not valid",
>       "rolled-back" => true }"

Need to mention that in logs I don't receive a more verbose message for the error, with all logs enabled(Trace, Debug, Error, etc).

Comment: Need to know more details, what do you mean copying over? Did the server start fine? what does it say in server.log file any errors? what are doing above to get that error? is that from web-console?

Comment: Answer to first question: I mean that I installed Teiid the way is recommended to be installed: 
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/teiid81final/Installation+Guide, by copying it over the JBoss structure of folders. 
Second question: Yes, the servers starts fine, it doesn't screen any error in log console.
Third question: In server.log it screens the same error as in administration console from web browser, if I enable all logs (Trace, Debug, Error, etc.).

Comment: Fourth question: I receive that error when I click test connection on the datasource from web administration console of JBoss+Teiid
Fifth question: Yes, the administration console I am talking about is the web administration console.

Comment: IMO, there must be some exception other than access one you mention. Teiid itself does not interfere with datasource configuration.

Comment: I've just copied the folders of teiid over the folders of jboss. When the teiid wasn't copied over jboss, test connection to datasource worked, when I copy teiid, test connection to datasource fails... it's clear is something in Teiid which doesn't let it work with the mysql datasource, but I don't know what because I receive a error message which doesn't tell something useful....

Comment: Yeah, this does not make any sense, it should not be overwriting anything AFAIK. You can try with later version and see if this is still an issue if possible. There is combined download now.

Comment: I've tried with latest version. still the same problem